# Newrelic for FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi, newrelic

I use this command in docker compose:
newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn main:app -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8000

but after running, I encountered with following error:

(14/ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0) newrelic.core.trace_cache ERROR - Runtime instrumentation error. An active trace already exists in the cache on thread_id 281472746332640. Report this issue to New Relic support.

How can I fix it?!
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Facing the same issue. let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initialized newrelic.ini config in main.py. It works and the errors were fixed:

```
import newrelic.agent

newrelic.agent.initialize('newrelic.ini')
```